# How to configure H2 DB connection details in DB Server component for Munit Test case?

Tags: database, server, mule, munit

1. I need to test DB query without connecting to original database.
2. I am trying to use Munit DB Server component to connect to H2 in memory DB instead of original database.
3. I have configured sql script in DB Server config module`dbserver:config name="DB_Server" database="test" doc:name="DB Server" sqlFile="CreateEmployee.sql" and also started DB server in munit Before suite
4. But my test case is connecting to original database instead of H2 DB
5. I have local H2 Db installed and DB properties

Please help me where and how to configure H2 DB related properties so that my test case works with in memory DB ?

Comment: I see the same issue. Were you able to resolve this at all?

Answer (score 0):

The MUnit DB component is meant to start a H2 DB instance, not to connect to an existing one.

The use case is, if you have your app parametrized to connect to a DB, you use the MUnit DB component to start an in memory DB and change the connection string in your app (as it's a parameter) to hit the new DB running in memory.

Makes sense?

Maybe this section of the documentation helps to clarify:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/munit-database-server#execution-environments

HTH

Comment: Link is broken.
Use https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/1.3/munit-database-server
to find the page.

Comment: I have set up the db.properties file with db.config=Test_Database_Config under src/test/resources. Also, I see the MUnit DB server started up ---// 
INFO  2020-01-08 12:40:15,369 [munit.01] org.mule.munit.DatabaseServer: Starting database server...
INFO  2020-01-08 12:40:15,514 [munit.01] org.mule.munit.DatabaseServer: Loading contacts.csv ... --//

However, I see the flow invokes the query on the original database and not the MUnit database/H2.

What else could I be missing? Any pointers would help.

Comment: I found out that the missing link in my case is not setting db.config from the db.properties (configured via Configuration Properties connector) property to config-ref attribute of the <db:select>. The proper setting would be as follows --- <db:select doc:name="Select" config-ref="${db.config}">. Also, the MUnit test case was written for MUnit v2.2.1 and Mule v4.2.1.